# Get Devicename as String from MTP-Device

Tags: powershell, usb, mtp, get-wmiobject

I try to automatically copy files from MTP-Devices (Smartphones) to my PC. I took several little code snippets from the internet for that and a lot of trial and error (several days), because I have no idea about powershell. But now everything works fine so far. The only problem is, that I have to manually put the name in for a device in my script, every time I took an other device. So I'm searching for a solution to automatically get the name from the actual device and save it in a variable.

I have tried this code:

```
Get-WmiObject -class win32_pnpentity -computername localhost | where-object {$_.HardwareID -like "*MTP*"} | format-list
```

As result i get:

```
__GENUS                     : 2
__CLASS                     : Win32_PnPEntity
__SUPERCLASS                : CIM_LogicalDevice
__DYNASTY                   : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH                   : Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\\VID_04E8&PID_6860&MS_COMP_MTP&SAMSUNG_ANDROID\\6&5F679FC&0
                              &0000"
__PROPERTY_COUNT            : 26
__DERIVATION                : {CIM_LogicalDevice, CIM_LogicalElement, CIM_ManagedSystemElement}
__SERVER                    : EXO-SURFACE
__NAMESPACE                 : root\cimv2
__PATH                      : \\EXO-SURFACE\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\\VID_04E8&PID_6860&MS_COMP_MTP&SAM
                              SUNG_ANDROID\\6&5F679FC&0&0000"
Availability                :
Caption                     : Galaxy S9+
ClassGuid                   : {eec5ad98-8080-425f-922a-dabf3de3f69a}
CompatibleID                : {USB\MS_COMP_MTP, USB\Class_06&SubClass_01&Prot_01, USB\Class_06&SubClass_01,
                              USB\Class_06...}
ConfigManagerErrorCode      : 0
ConfigManagerUserConfig     : False
CreationClassName           : Win32_PnPEntity
Description                 : SM-G965F
DeviceID                    : USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&MS_COMP_MTP&SAMSUNG_ANDROID\6&5F679FC&0&0000
ErrorCleared                :
ErrorDescription            :
HardwareID                  : {USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&REV_0400&MS_COMP_MTP&SAMSUNG_Android,
                              USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&MS_COMP_MTP&SAMSUNG_Android,
                              USB\SAMSUNG_MOBILE&MS_COMP_MTP&SAMSUNG_Android, USB\SAMSUNG_MOBILE&MI_00...}
InstallDate                 :
LastErrorCode               :
Manufacturer                : Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.
Name                        : Galaxy S9+
PNPClass                    : WPD
PNPDeviceID                 : USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&MS_COMP_MTP&SAMSUNG_ANDROID\6&5F679FC&0&0000
PowerManagementCapabilities :
PowerManagementSupported    :
Present                     : True
Service                     : WUDFWpdMtp
Status                      : OK
StatusInfo                  :
SystemCreationClassName     : Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName                  : EXO-SURFACE
PSComputerName              : EXO-SURFACE
```

This looks very fine, because for the Name it's recognized as "Galaxy S9+" like it should. So do anyone here know, how to extract this Device Name into an variable? I would be very thankful, because I am a real noob in powershell and it's a project to help my parents, who have their problems with technology.

Comment: if you remove the `Format-List` [which gives out _formatting code_, not normal objects], you should be able to wrap the code in `$VarName = ().Name` to get just the value of the `.Name` property into the `$VarName` of your choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. With your help, I've got everything working!

Comment: you are quite welcome! glad to have helped a tad ... [*grin*]

Comment: is it not possible to do it this way too? `$getName = Get-WmiObject -class win32_pnpentity -computername localhost | where-object {$_.HardwareID -like "*MTP*"} | select Name
$getName`